# OpenGL how to properly calculate the camera matrix with GLM

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math, assimp

I am working to an OpenGL graphic engine and I'm experiencing a very odd issue. Basically I'm importing (through Assimp) a .DAE scene (made in Cinema4D) which also contains a Camera. The camera is in the origin and rotated 20 degrees to the left and 20 degrees up, so that a section of the cube should appear in the lower right corner of the viewport.

[image]
When rendering I first calculate the "global" lookAt matrix, by applying the world transformation matrix of the camera node within the scene graph to the lookAt matrix:

```
cameraMatrix = transform * glm::lookAt(camera->position, camera->lookAt, camera->upward);
```

and then use it to calculate the final meshes' modelview matrices:

```
// mesh.second is the world matrix
mat4 modelvMatrix = renderList->cameraMatrix * mesh.second;
```

which is then combined with the projection matrix and fed to the shader. However the result (textures are not working yet) seems like "mirrored", as if the transformations were applied conversely:

[image]
Doing some math manually **using the same transformation matrix**:

```
//cameraMatrix = transform * glm::lookAt(camera->position, camera->lookAt, camera->upward);
cameraMatrix = camera->getCameraMatrix(transform);

mat4 Camera::getCameraMatrix(mat4p transform)
{
    auto invTr = glm::inverseTranspose(mat3(transform));
    auto pos = vec3(transform * vec4(position, 1));
    auto dir = invTr * glm::normalize(lookAt - position);
    auto upw = invTr * upward;
    return glm::lookAt(pos, pos + dir, upw);
}
```

seems to solve the problem:

[image]
However I am not sure if the output is entirely right because it is not perfectly specular to the first image. The local transformation matrix of the camera node is:

```
mat4x4(
    (0.939693,  0.000000, -0.342020, 0.000000),
    (0.116978,  0.939693,  0.321394, 0.000000),
    (0.321394, -0.342020,  0.883022, 0.000000),
    (0.000000, -0.000000,  0.000000, 1.000000))
```

How should I properly calculate the camera matrix?

**EDIT**

I've been asking about the calculus of the matrices:

```
        mat4 modelvMatrix = renderList->cameraMatrix * mesh.second;
        mat4 renderMatrix = projectionMatrix * modelvMatrix;
        shaderProgram->setMatrix("renderMatrix", renderMatrix);
        mesh.first->render();
```

and the shader code:

```
const std::string Source::VertexShader= R"(
    #version 430 core

    layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
    layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
    layout(location = 2) in vec2 vertexTexCoord;

    uniform mat4 renderMatrix;

    out vec2 texCoord;

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = renderMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        texCoord = vertexTexCoord;
    }
)";
```

```
const std::string Source::FragmentShader= R"(
    #version 430 core

    uniform sampler2D sampler;

    in vec2 texCoord;

    out vec3 color;

    void main()
    {
        color = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        //color = texture(sampler, texCoord);
    }
)";
```

Comment: Doesn't the world transformation go first? Like `cameraMatrix = glm::lookAt(...) * transform;`?

Comment: I don't think so, anyway I tried but the result remains unchanged.

Comment: You should show as your shader code.

Comment: Such problems usually comes from mess in transformation order of axes, first make sure that you axes in Cinema3D match/converted to OpenGL. Second make sure you apply transformation correctly:gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

Comment: I added the code. Unfortunately Cinema4D has no options for swapping axes, and the order of the matrices seems right as you can see from the new code. However the strange thing here is that manually applying the transform to the camera parameters seems to produce the desired output, while simply multiplying the transform and the lookAt seems to mess things up. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

First, this is wrong:

```
cameraMatrix = transform * glm::lookAt(camera->position, camera->lookAt, camera->upward);
```

The [correct order](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/) is as follows:

> MVP = P * V * M;

Where P,V,M are projection, view and model matrices respectively.

Also,that expression doesn't make sense because your glm::lookAt already calculates lookAt matrix based on camera's transform.(if we imply that your 'transform'  is camera's model matrix)

Now, regarding `glm::lookAt()`. Don't use it to get view (camera) matrix. While it does return you a matrix that is oriented in a direction you specified, this is not going to be a correct view matrix because the eye position (translation part of this matrix) is not inversed as it should in the case of view matrix.

The simpliest way to get a correct view matrix is to inverse its model matrix.

```
glm::mat4 V = glm::inverse(M);
```

That's it. Now you can fetch your 'V' into shader or calculate MVP matrix on CPU.

Comment: The name cameraMatrix is a bit confusing, it is actually V. So I do: V = cameraModel * glm::lookAt and then for every mesh MVP = P * V * meshModel. Are you sure this isn't right? Regarding my usage of lookAt please note that it is called with the local parameters of the camera, which are often default values because things like rotation are stored within the node's transformation matrix. So I need to apply it somehow.

Comment: @Shepard I guarantee you for all 100% that inversing camera's model matrix gives you completely correct view matrix. :)

Comment: The statement "Now, regarding `glm::lookAt()`. Don't use it to get view (camera) matrix." is just wrong.  `glm::lookAt()` is exactly there to calculate a view matrix, and its translation part is not inverted for that use case (neither is any other part). Also, the "correct" multiplication order depends on the conventions one is using, `M*V*P` can be as valid is `P*V*M`, and fixed function GL where the order was defined by the GL is long gone.

Comment: @derhass  if you try to manipulate your camera, and I mean both move it and orient ,using lookat () vs inverse ()  ,you will find that they don't result in the same transform.I used to have a lot of issues applying complex transformations to camera by using glm::lookAt.  For me, inverse of the model matrix solved it all. I really didn't try to figure out what's wrong with that method in glm but the fact is - it doesn't provide 100% correct view matrix.  My frame of reference here Unity game engine and Adobe AfterEffects.

Comment: Well, glm's `lookAt` does exactly what it is documented to do: create a view matrix for the specified  camera position and lookat direction (and orientation via the up vector). It does so by following the legacy GL conventions of using a right-handed view space, where `-z` is the lookat direction. If you use different conventions, it will fail.